Reconciling Evolution and Whitehead's Process Philosophy: Is Randomness the Key to Creativity in Nature?
I am somewhat interested in Whitehead's process philosophy and reality.
The following points puzzled me:

How can the survival of the fittest (evolution) be explained through process philosophy?
Because evolution assumes randomness in nature, which is needed to explain random mutations, and this randomness is the source of creativity in the process of evolution.
So, did Whitehead assume randomness is a fundamental property of nature (which I can't directly see from his writing)?

Questions:

How to explain evolution in process philosophy (from Process and Reality)?
Is randomness assumed to be in nature, or is it derived from something more fundamental?
What is the source of creativity? (What is God is he talking about?)

I know the above writing may sound vague if you understand those concepts, but I don't know how to talk about them; they are very perplexing to me. Also suggest me some resources.

Actually, evolution does not assume "randomness" in the relevant sense. Mutations only have to appear random from inside the host ecosystem, and deterministic universe is perfectly capable of providing such. Evolution theory does not need more than that, and current physics is compatible with both deterministic and indeterministic interpretations. This said, Whitehead, like Peirce and James, was a free will libertarian, his "process" involves indeterministic "prehensions", see Viney-Crosby, Free will in process perspective.

Maybe first post your first question about process philosophy, and then after that, do a separate post with a follow up question.
